# Define and Execute Dynamic Methods

Tags: c#

```
private ComplexAdvertismentsQuery QueryForm1(string searchQuery)
private ComplexAdvertismentsQuery QueryForm2(string searchQuery)
private ComplexAdvertismentsQuery QueryForm3(string searchQuery)
private ComplexAdvertismentsQuery QueryForm4(string searchQuery)
...
```

then i check

```
query = QueryForm1(searchQuery);
if (query != null)
{
}

query = QueryForm2(searchQuery);
if (query != null)
{
}
```

can i make this dynamic?

i look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exczf7b9.aspx and try with Type but this is not class it is jut method.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? Please clarify.

Comment: I think you need to add a lot more context to this question; there are definitely people here who *can* give you `DynamicMethod` examples, but it is meaningless unless the question is *very* clear.

Comment: Calling methods through reflection can slow your program down. Wouldn't it be more useful to have an array of `Func<string, ComplexAdvertismentsQuery>` and iterate on it ?

Comment: @senzacionale, its not clear what you want to achieve by dynamic invocation here. Perhaps you should look at the way suggested by Nekresh.

Comment: i solve the problem by this example http://sadi02.wordpress.com/2008/05/14/dynamic-static-and-non-static-method-invocation-in-c/

Comment: Nekresh thx for this tip, do you know how slow? I know it is hard to say but generally how musc when using reflection?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with an array of strong-typed delegates and iterate on it to execute all your methods.

```
var listOfQueries = new List<Func<string, ComplexAdvertismentsQuery>> {
  QueryForm1, QueryForm2, QueryForm3, QueryForm4
};

foreach (var queryForm in listOfQueries) {
  var query = queryForm(searchQuery);

  if (query != null) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

If needed, you can populate the list by used reflection and get the corresponding delegate for each one, and pay the cost for reflection only once.

The drawback of this method is that all your methods must have the same prototype (`ComplexAdvertismentsQuery method(string)` here).